# Run GDB server in Qt Android Application

Tags: android, c++, qt, cmake

I have a project that uses Qt framework to build android application. I'm using CMake as build system and CLion as IDE. Currently my CMake script can build `.apk` package and install it to the device.

Now I want to debug my application. The problem is that I don't know how to run `gdbserver` on android and attach it to the process using Qt. It seems it is possible to embed gdb server into `.apk` package using `androiddeployqt`:

```
--gdbserver: Adds the gdbserver to the package.
    By default the gdbserver is bundled for debug pacakges.
```

But I can't find any information about how to run this `gdbserver` and how to connect a client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that if `--gdbserver` is enabled `androiddeployqt` puts `libgdbserver.so` (which is actually just renamed `gdbserver` binary) into `libs/<abi>/` directory of `.apk` package. You can run it using follow command from host computer:

```
adb shell run-as com.package.name /data/data/com.package.name/lib/libgdbserver.so --once +/data/data/com.package.name/debug_socket --attach $PID
```